# textkit for newer version of swift is not available

Tags: swift, textkit

I need something like `textkit` swift to implement a text editor in my application. the problem is all `textkit` code samples and  informations are in older version of swift ,which swift 4 dose not supports it and it has more than 100 errors. dosen any one know why there is no new information about `textkit` recently. I wonder if `textkit` is outdated? if yes then please tell me what is in its place right now that have most abilities like `textkit` and if no and its not outdated please give me some new information about it. appreciate any help.

to know more look at this little codes of textkit,

```
let scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView.init(frame: CGRectZero)
let textStorage:NSTextStorage = NSTextStorage()
let layoutManger: NSLayoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
let fontArribuates = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)]

var titleTextView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)
var contentTextView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

or like this

```
// MARK: Life Cycle
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.title = "Post"
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    // error is : 'None' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set`
}
```

the errors are like this that `'CGRectZero' is unavailable in Swift` or `'systemFontOfSize' has been renamed to 'systemFont(ofSize:)'` or `'None' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set`

Comment: Can you update your question with a small code sample that gives an error?

Comment: @PhillipMills I posted some samples. really thank you for your care and help

Answer (score 2):

TextKit is not outdated.

Just perform the suggested changes or use Xcode's code migration feature to perform the changes automatically (Edit>Convert>To Current Swift Syntax).

Instead of `CGRectZero` use `CGRect.zero`. Instead of `systemFontOfSize(...)` use `systemFont(ofSize:)` and `[]` instead of `UIRectEdge.None`.

Comment: thank you it seems helpfull, but in (Edit>Convert>To Current Swift Syntax) I have an Error `After using 'Minimize Inference' you need to follow the manual steps detailed in the migration guide to complete the conversion.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that TextKit has been replaced, just that the syntax has been updated some in newer iOS/Swift versions.

For example, your first section works for me in a playground with the following changes:

```
let scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
let textStorage:NSTextStorage = NSTextStorage()
let layoutManger: NSLayoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
let fontArribuates = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]

var titleTextView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
var contentTextView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

For your second example, the error message suggests...

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge([])
```

...but that's a quick guess.